# ¿Cómo manipular el DOM en Javascript para que los datos ingresados en un input aparezcan en otro input?

Tags: javascript, dom, input, listener

Quiero que se ingrese un nombre en un input (etiqueta txtName) y después el mismo dato ingresado se muestre en el otro input con la etiqueta inpName (pudiera incorporarse un readonly para este último input). Lo cierto es que el navegador tira este error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment at HTMLButtonElement.user y entiendo que lo que dice es que se está tratando de igualar el elemento del lado izquierdo con el del lado derecho y no está permitido, es decir, es invalido para Javascript... pero no sé cómo resolver a través de la manipulación del DOM que lo ingresado en un input aparezca en otro

```
user.addEventListener('click', function user(){
    name = document.getElementById('txtName');
    document.getElementById('inpName') = document.getElementById('txtName');
})
```

Comment: Eso no lo puedes hacer de esa forma, tienes que editar las propiedades del input con el id `inpName`, hay algo que no entiendo bien `inpName` ya existe o tienes que crearlo??? xq esto cambia la solución, si pude añada algo del html para poder dar una respuesta acertada Saludos

Comment: Si, @rene el input tendría que crearlo dinámicamente

Comment: ok entonces es necesario saber donde quieres crearlo, es decir el padre donde lo vas a insertar, para crear un input solo necesitas hacer esto `var newInput = document.CreateElement('input')` ya después le seteas los valores del `value`, `id` y todo lo que quieras y por ultimo al padre le dices `padre.appendChild(input)` por eso te digo que es neceario conocer el padre

Comment: debería ser añadido al body, es decir, body.appendChild(input) pero no logro todavía dar con la solución

Comment: no no, sería `document.body.appendChild(input)`

Comment: ah, exacto, no lo escribí completo...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129404/discussion-between-rene-and-otromascomotu).

Comment: `user` que es, un `button`, otro `input`???

Comment: otra cosa arriba me equivoqué es `document.createElement('input')`

Comment: user vendría siendo un botón

Comment: Estás tratando de asignar un elemento HTML, remplazándolo con otro. Solo necesitas los valores y, como ya definiste la variable `name` para el primer campo, esto debe resolver el problema: `document.getElementById('inpName').value = name.value;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
(function(){
var txtName = document.getElementById('txtName');
txtName.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
  if (this.value === ''){
   var newInput = document.getElementById('inpName');
   if (newInput !== null){
    newInput.remove();
   }
  }else{
    var newInput = document.getElementById('inpName');
    if (newInput === null){
      newInput = document.createElement('input');
      newInput.id = 'inpName';
      newInput.setAttribute('readonly', true);
      document.body.appendChild(newInput);
    }

    newInput.value = txtName.value;
  }  
})
})
();
```

```html
<input id="txtName" />
```

Mira en este ejemplo lo queue hago es tener un input donde se puede escribir después, en el evento `keyup` que ese evento se dispara cuando una tecla se levanta, le pongo la función que verifica si el valor es vacío busca el input y lo elimina si existe, si no es vacío que hace busca el input si no existe lo crea con el `document.createElement('input');`, le pongo un id, lo pongo readonly y lo agrego al body por último después de que exista o sea creado le pongo el mismo valor que tiene el otro input, Saludos